# SAM template.yaml from VS Code launch.json?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm using an AWS SAM debug configuration in VS Code to execute Lambda code for Typescript/Node 14 inside a Docker container. I've run into problems of dependencies not being included in the Lambda image, and I presume that building the Lambda explicitly using *sam build* should resolve that. However, I can't find the template files that VS Code generates. Is there a way to export my settings from VS Code's *launch.json*, or otherwise get hold of the *template.yaml*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAM template will be generated, at least on Mac, in a directory under
*/tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode*. E.g.:

> /tmp/aws-toolkit-vscode/vsctkENG01e/app___vsctk___template.yaml

This directory gets mapped into the Docker container.